# <s:if> test expression evaluation for boolean value doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, boolean-expression

I want to check value of variable `bool_val` using Struts 2 tag `<s:if>` but it's not working.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<%boolean bool_val=true;%>
real value : <%=bool_val%></br>
expression evaluated value : 
<s:if test="%{bool_val==true}">
    TRUE
</s:if><s:else>
    FLASE
</s:else>
```

I also tried following test expressions too, but still not working.

```
<!-- 
bool_val
bool_val==true
%{bool_val}
%{bool_val==true}
%{bool_val=="true"}
 -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a scriptlet variable in Struts tags unless you put this variable to the value stack. But you'd better not use a scriptlet variable, but the variable value.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<%boolean bool_val=true;%>
real value : <%=bool_val%><br/>
expression evaluated value : 
<s:set var="bool_val"><%=bool_val%></s:set>
<s:if test="#bool_val == 'true'">
    TRUE
</s:if><s:else>
    FALSE
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use struts tag to create a variable like this

```xml
<s:set var="bool_val" value="true" />
expression evaluated value : 
<s:if test="%{#bool_val == true}">
    TRUE
</s:if><s:else>
    FALSE
</s:else>
```

Here is a [sample tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a shorter version to the one suggested by Visruth CV :

```
<s:set var="foo" value="true" />

expression evaluated value : 
<s:if test="foo">
    TRUE
</s:if><s:else>
    FALSE
</s:else>
```

In case you want to check the boolean value against an Action attribute, here is the way to go :

```
class FooAction extends ActionSupport {
    private Boolean _bar = true;

    public Boolean isBar() { return _bar; }
}
```

And in the jsp file :

```
expression evaluated value : 
<s:if test="isBar()">
    TRUE
</s:if>
<s:else>
    FALSE
</s:else>
```

Comment: I like this answer better because calling the `isBar()` property method is less complex and error prone then the selected answer by @roman-c.

Answer (score 1):

If getter method for your boolean variable in Action class is `isBool()`
then use `<s:if test="bool">`.
The key is to remove `is` from the method name and use.
For example, if method is `isApple()` use `<s:if test="apple">`.